# A web page is slowing down firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

when we click save button below message is display only firefox browser:
A web page is slowing down, what do you want to do?

[image: below screenshot is coming]

Answer (score 0):

try putting your js code or file at the end of your code not in the starting or maybe add a webkit